# how to receive data from user with request with less code in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Ι want to recive 10 variables from my front side for example so what Ι do Ι have to write like below :

```
$item1 = $request->get('item1');
$item2 = $request->get('item2');
$item3 = $request->get('item3');
$item4 = $request->get('item4');
$item5 = $request->get('item5');
$item6 = $request->get('item6');
```

Ι want to know if there is any way to write it in 1 line of code as it makes my code so messy, or any other optimized or better way to get the variables from a user with less code

Comment: it depends on what do you want to do after getting variable, for example mass assignment for insert to database or update,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can do like below.

```
extract($request->only(['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6']));
```

Laravel have `except` function also.

```
extract($request->except(['_token','id']));// it will get array of all request data except _token and id.
```

More Description

```
//$request->only(['item1','item2','item3']) will give you below array
$requestArr = ['item1'=>'value1','item2'=>'value2','item3'=>'value3'];

//extract will convert array key's as php variables
extract($requestArr);

// now you can use those php variable

echo $item1 ?? 'item1 is not a variable';
```

Answer (score 0):

Inlude all the column names is in your model like below

```
class User extends Model
{
protected $fillable=['item1', 'item2',...... And s on] ;
}
```

And in your controller:

```
Public function(Request $request)
{
 $user=create([$request->all()]) ;
}
```

And this should be work... If it is not let me know